# Azure CosmosDB Emulator on Docker doesn't generate certificate

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to run the Azure CosmosDB Emulator in a Docker container as according to these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-docker

The main commands described are:

`md %LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulatorCert 2>null
docker run -v %LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulatorCert:C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\CosmosDBEmulatorCert -P -t -i -m 2GB microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator`

The next instruction is to import the SSL certificate on the host:
`cd /d %LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulatorCert
powershell .\importcert.ps1`

But the folder is empty - there's no certificate and no powershell script.

Similarly, the `C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\CosmosDBEmulatorCert` folder on the container is empty as well.

When everything was initializing, there's a line saying:

`-a----       10/18/2018   4:50 PM            513 CosmosDbEmulatorCert.cer`

But I can't see a certificate anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Use these instructions instead:
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator/

The **run** command showed there is slighted different. It uses `--mount` instead of `-v` option to handle volumes and binds:

(Replace `%hostDirectory%` for your path where you want to store the certificates like `C:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Local\azure-cosmosdb-emulator-hostd` or declare it in the script)

```
 docker run --name azure-cosmosdb-emulator --memory 2GB --mount "type=bind,source=%hostDirectory%,destination=C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\bind-mount" -P --interactive --tty microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator
```

You can then close the interactive shell. It will remain running.

Comment: There are no longer instructions at the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found the certificate in the container in `C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\bind-mount`

Answer (score 0):

Instructions at URL - https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator/ works fine.

I would still like to suggest a few changes though -

**Step 1:**

```
md cd $env:LOCALAPPDATA\CosmosDBEmulatorCert

docker run --name azure-cosmosdb-emulator --memory 2GB -p 8081:8081 --mount "type=bind,source=$env:LOCALAPPDATA\CosmosDBEmulatorCert,destination=C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\bind-mount" -P --interactive --tty microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator
```

**Step2:**

- Open another powershell window and run below set of commands

  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

  $env:LOCALAPPDATA\CosmosDBEmulatorCert\importcert.ps1

  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Restricted

**Step3:**

- Browse to below URL:

  https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html

You should not receive certificate error anymore with accessibility on localhost